# How to connect the signal valueChanged from QLineEdit to a custom slot in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlineedit

I need to connect the valueChanged signal from QLineEdit to a custom slot programatically. I know how to do the connection by using Qt Designer and doing the connection with graphical interface but I would like to do it programmatically so I can learn more about the Signals and Slots.

This is what I have that doesn't work.

.cpp file

```
// constructor
connect(myLineEdit, SIGNAL(valueChanged(static QString)), this, SLOT(customSlot()));

void MainWindow::customSlot()
{
    qDebug()<< "Calling Slot";
}
```

.h file

```
private slots:
    void customSlot();
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`QLineEdit` does not seem to have `valueChanged` signal, but `textChanged` (refer to the Qt documentation for complete list of supported signals).
You need to change your `connect()` function call too. It should be:

```
connect(myLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(customSlot()));
```

If you need the handle the new text value in your slot, you can define it as `customSlot(const QString &newValue)` instead, so your connection will look like:

```
connect(myLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(customSlot(const QString &)));
```

Comment: Changed valueChanged to textChanged and static QString to const QString & and worked. I don't know how I missed that, specially static QString (wow), thanks a lot. Also thanks a lot for the second example since I was also wondering about the usage of the parameter. Thanks a LOT

Comment: [Here's Qt 5's new way to connect,](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)


`connect(myLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
            this, &MainWindow::customSlot);`

Answer (score 0):

Here also with lambda if interested:

```
connect(myLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [=](QString obj) { customSlot(obj); });
```